# como acceder a los datos de un archivo .json desde un .bat

Tags: json, .bat, desarrollo

Tengo esta estructura de JSON

```
{
"nodes3": [
      "http://www.Pregunta.com/"`introducir el código aquí`
    ],
}
```

Quiero obtener los datos del JSON desde un .BAT

Comment: hola porfavor revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask